# Unity3d build don't destroy on load not working

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a Unity project where my first scene sets up some objects that I dont want to be destroyed. The next scene is then automatically loaded with the undestroyed objects still around.

This works fine in the editor but as soon as I build it (for Windows) it doesn't work.

Please help!!!

EDIT: I'm using `DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);` to preserve my objects. Have also found [this link](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-5-bug-dontdestroyonload-with-audiosource-failing-on-windows-standalone-build.344497/)

Comment: How can anyone help with such little detail (like code and perhaps a working project that demonstrates the issue).

Comment: Also `transform.gameObject` is another way of saying `this`.

Comment: Just using what the Unity docs said. I am aware of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

OK so it turns out there's a little bug with unity that means that `DontDestroyOnLoad();` is not 100% reliable when the project is built for a windows standalone build.

The fix is to make the object(s) that you want to not be destroyed between levels into prefabs. This way unity won't prune them and they are preserved.

Comment: WHERE DID U FIND THIS (OK so it turns out there's a little bug with unity that means that DontDestroyOnLoad(); is not 100% reliable when the project is built for a windows standalone build)

Comment: Check out the link in the question.

Comment: Is there a bug? @RASS pls share bug report link.

Comment: I don't have the bug report link. I'm just going on what I've read.